# Ship block templates or block template parts with plugins

Tags: filters, hooks, templates, block-editor

Using the following code one can ship CLASSIC PHP templates for custom post types registered in plugins. An example for a custom post type named MOVIE:

```
function my_template_include( $template ) {
    global $post;

    if ( isset( $post ) ) {

        if ( is_post_type_archive( 'movie' ) || is_tax( 'movie_category' ) || is_tax( 'movie_tag' ) ) {

            $file = locate_template( array( 'archive-movie.php' ) );
            if ( '' !== $file ) {
                $template = $file;
            } else {
                $template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/archive-movie.php';
            }
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'my_template_include' );
```

My question is, is there an equivalent filter to do the same for BLOCK HTML templates/template parts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: note that you can't predict how a block theme is structured so the best you could do is provide a template part that the user would then need to integrate into their themes templates, unless it was a total page takeover. Block patterns are a better solution